# ActiveState Perl 5.14 fails to compare certain values?

Tags: windows, perl

Basically, using the following code on a file stream, I get the following:

```
$basis = $2 * 1.0;
$cost = ($basis - 2500.0) ** 1.05;
# The above should ensure that both cost & basis are floats
printf "  %f -> %f", $basis, $cost;
if ($basis gt $cost) {  # <- *** THIS WAS MY ERROR: gt forces lexical!
    $cost = $basis;
    printf " -> %f", $cost;
}
```

Outputs:

```
  10667.000000 -> 12813.438340
  30667.000000 -> 47014.045519
  26667.000000 -> 40029.842300
  66667.000000 -> 111603.373367 -> 66667.000000
  8000.000000 -> 8460.203780
  10667.000000 -> 12813.438340
  73333.000000 -> 123807.632158 -> 73333.000000
  6667.000000 -> 6321.420427 -> 6667.000000
  80000.000000 -> 136071.379474 -> 80000.000000
```

As you can see, for most values, the code appears to work fine.

But for some values.... 66667, 80000, and a few others, ActivePerl 5.14 tells me that 66667 > 1111603!!!

Does anyone know anything about this - or have an alternate Perl interpreter I might use (Windows).  Because this is ridiculous.

Comment: What is the content of the `$basis` variable? May be it is a string?

Comment: you can see from the output, which shows various $cost -> $basis using printf taking %f (which requires a float)... so, no, I don't think it is a string.

Comment: `which requires a float` it does not mean that it 'requires' a float, it means that it will try to format the output to the specified format. http://ideone.com/jU3wI

Comment: Okay, you've made me a believer.  It's doing a lexical compare.  How do I force it to do a numerical compare?  Your suggestion produces the same output as before :(

Comment: @Mordachai in Perl, `>` **IS** numerical compare, while `gt` is lexical compare. I don't know why your code got such results. Can you paste the whole script?

Comment: Check the content of the variables before `if` statement.. `use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($basis);`

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help.  I was looking at stale output data, so I wasn't evaluating the actual changes to my code.  Hence my confusion!  D'oh! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a lexical comparison instead of the numerical one

```
$cost = ($basis - 2500.0) ** 1.05;
printf "  %f -> %f", $basis, $cost;
if ($basis > $cost) {
    $cost = $basis;
    printf " -> %f", $cost;
}
```

ps: revised to match the updated question

Comment: That doesn't do anything different.  I've edited my question to better show that it isn't a type issue.  At least, not that I can possibly tell.

Comment: Your explanation sounds reasonable - that it's doing a lexical greater or less than.  But how to force it to do a numerical comparison?! Adding numbers, multiplying by 1, none of those seem to do a thing. :(

Comment: @Mordachai By addition of the zero it should automatically cast the type. Are you sure you did not skip some part of the code?

Comment: In Perl, `>` always does numerical comparison (well, unless you have an object that overloads comparisons).  `gt` is the lexical comparison operator.

Comment: @cjm Sorry, I did not use Perl for a very looong time :) But from the question it was clear that it happens during the lexical comparison.

Comment: You were right that what I was seeing was the result of a lexical compare.  My confusion over stale output made it hard to see that it was working once I changed if ($cost lt $basis) to if ($cost < $basis).  Apparently Perl uses the lt/gt to mean lexical, and < > to mean numerical.  Thanks :)

Comment: @Cheery, you should revise this answer to match the revised question.  The real problem was that he used `gt` when he meant `<` (and then fixed the problem when he copied it to his question).

Comment: There's no floats in Perl. We just have numbers. We don't cast variables: the operations convert scalar *values* as needed.

Answer (score 3):

The first few chapters of *Learning Perl* will clear this up for you. Scalar values are can be either strings or numbers, or both at the same time. Perl uses the operator to decide how to treat them. If you want to do numeric comparisons, you use the numeric comparison operators. If you want to do string comparisons, you use the string comparison operators.

The scalar values themselves don't have a type, despite other answers and comments using words like "float" and "cast". It's just strings and numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you need to compare as lexical, but you can force it using sprintf

```
$basis_real = sprintf("%015.6f",$basis);
$cost_real = sprintf("%015.6f",$cost);
printf "  %s -> %s", $basis_real, $cost_real;
if ($basis_real gt $cost_real) {
     $cost = $basis;
     printf " -> %015.6f", $cost;
}
```

Output:

```
  00010667.000000 -> 00012813.438340
  00030667.000000 -> 00047014.045519
  00026667.000000 -> 00040029.842300
  00066667.000000 -> 00111603.373367
  00008000.000000 -> 00008460.203780
  00010667.000000 -> 00012813.438340
  00073333.000000 -> 00123807.632158
  00006667.000000 -> 00006321.420427 -> 00006667.000000
  00080000.000000 -> 00136071.379474
```

The reason it was failing as you noted, the lexical compare does character to character compare, so when it hits the decimal point in `6667.` it actually is alphabetically before `111603.` , so it is greater.

To fix this, you must make all the numbers the same size, especially where the decimal lines up.  The %015 is the total size of number, including the period and the decimals.